# Manga where the MC was the leader of the strongest sect, and then wakes up in a tomb or coffin with a maxed out game system

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

I remember at the beginning that he woke up in a tomb or coffin. He was said to have been the strongest sage cultivator back in the ancient times. The mc transmigrated or got reincarnated to the body with a maxed out game system. When the body was still alive in the past he was the leader of the strongest sect. The sect has declined and almost gone when the mc is transmigrated.

There is a woman who argued with I think it is the current sect owner. She then kicks the lid off of the coffin and mc comes out. The current sect owner thought he was a demon and attacked and told it to get out of the ancestor's body. That was as far as I got. Need help with finding it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If, as per your comment, the correct answer was given, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is *[Your Ancestor is Online](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/your-ancestor-is-online/reviews#76849)*

> An introvert who has played an online game 100 times is so close to beating it but never can!  But what's this?  Restricted mode unlocked?  A cheat menu?! After creating his new character with max cheat stats and assuming it'll be an easy win, the main character gets isekai'd into the world of the game- as the previously-dead ancestor of a sect.  Unfortunately for him, he's not as OP as the 'cheats' insinuated, so don't expect a dime-a-dozen trashy, instant 'I am GOD' manhua here.
>
> "I didn't sign up to be isekai'd!" "Well, you should've read the fine print in the user agreement, lol." "But I'm just a normal guy!" "Don't sweat the small details, earthman."

### The scene where he is shot after coming out of the sarcophagus

[image: Zhang, an arrow in his chest, confronting Master Zhang and Gu Xiaoyun]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please include details of the story that show how it matches the question.  You might want to check out [answer].

Answer (score 0):

***My Apprentices are all Female Devils*** — this seems similar to what you described.

[image: My Apprentices are all Female Devils]

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please add more details to explain how this work answers the question. You can find [tips on how to write a good story identification answer in our guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/7957).